# Is it possible to clear the console tab during runtime in Intellij with Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Im trying to clear the console tab in Intellij during run time with Java.

Any ideas?

This is what i tried:

```
System.out.print("\033\143");

    public static void clrscr(){
        //Clears Screen in java
        try {
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            else
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {}
    }

    public final static void clearConsole()
    {
        try
        {
            final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

            if (os.contains("Windows"))
            {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
            }
            else
            {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
            }
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            //  Handle any exceptions.
        }
    }

    public static void clearScreen() {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Are these three different methods that you've tried? and what error or output do you get with each one of them?

Comment: I usually just close it and open a new one.

Comment: Yes, it is the different methods tried.

Comment: You need to write a plugin and implement `com.intellij.execution.filters.ConsoleInputFilterProvider`+`com.intellij.execution.actions.ConsoleActionsPostProcessor` or `com.intellij.execution.filters.ConsoleDependentFilterProvider`.

Comment: I do not know how to do that you just said. Can you provide some more info/help?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html

Comment: A moderator deleted my answer that Grep Console plugin supports it now...

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a shortcut to `Clear All` on the Console from `Preferences > Keymap`. In the following screenshot I am assigning the shortcut `ALT SHIFT 1` to clear the console.

To test this just place your cursor in the console and use that keystroke combination.

That's the easy part. Next you can use `java.awt.Robot` to exeucte that keystroke combination. For example:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public void clearConsole() {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Use of `Robot` can be a bit tricky so you'll likely have to play around with that including adding a keystroke combination to switch focus to the console before executing `ALT SHIFT 1`