# Clearing console in Intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Could anyone tell me if it's possible to clear console in intellij-idea and how?

So far I have tried:

```
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
System.out.flush();
```

and:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
```

but any of those did work.

I'm using Intellij-idea ultimate 2017 2.4 and Linux Mint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc If any of those suggestions worked for me except printing new line 50x i would have not created this topic

Comment: Write a plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102201/is-it-possible-to-clear-the-console-tab-during-runtime-in-intellij-with-java#comment79167189_46102201

Comment: The best thing would be to implement it into https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole and send a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin for clearing it when it matches some output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can, think of that window as a log file.

BTW, why would you want to clear that?

Comment: I'm developing a chess game and need to refresh the console everytime a player makes a move.

Comment: @stilltryingbutstillsofar Why not just print a delimiter line.

Comment: @Meo Currently i print like 50 newlines but I would like to know if there's a way to clear it in intellij instead of doing this.

Comment: For debugging purposes it's good to be able to clear the console (other IDEs have this feature).

Answer (score 0):

"Right" click over the console and select "clear all"

[image]

Comment: OP wants it from the code, not from the IDE

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA console is not a real terminal, so there is no command to clear it from your Java code.

See the issue [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000585870-Clear-IntelliJ-console-from-java).

Try run your application in other terminal, then you can make a function like this:

```
public static void ClearConsole(){
    try{
        String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name") //Check the current operating system
          
        if(operatingSystem.contains("Windows")){        
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls");
            Process startProcess = pb.inheritIO.start();
            startProcess.waitFor();
        } else {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("clear");
            Process startProcess = pb.inheritIO.start();

            startProcess.waitFor();
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```